# Couldn't copy file from Windows external hard disk to Lubuntu USB

Tags: windows, lubuntu, windows-10, copy, copy-and-paste

My system information:

- Lubuntu 18.04 LTS
- PCmanFM 1.2.5
- My Lubuntu is installed directly on a pendrive.

Here is the bug I got while copying `.ttf` from Windows 10:

> Error when getting information for file “/media/starlight/Windows 10 Pro/Windows/Fonts/cour.ttf”: Input/output error

[image: Screenshot: error dialog]

I tried to copy some fonts from Windows 10 which installed as the primary OS on my computer. For now, I downloaded fonts from the internet. But I want to understand the reason and get solutions because I really need to send/get files from PCs. (This pendrive works as mobile-workspace of mine.)

Comment: IO (input/output) errors are hardware issues and are not bugs.  If I had the error, I'd `cp` (copy the file; even if to `/dev/null`) to see the error in full which is easier in a terminal. IO error implies hardware issue, which is why I'd take note (exploring `dmesg` or system logs, then check SMART or check the health of the drive to ensure it's not starting to fail). Glitches can happen in theory because of power surges (ie. random), so it may be a one-off, but I'd explore details in logs (or via re-doing the operation & taking note with my first `cp` or `cat` )

Comment: Thanks for guiding me to check issues. Here is my latest line in syslog: `Jan 29 22:44:55 Astral kernel: [ 2517.356194] audit: type=1400 audit(1548776695.085:22): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/usr/bin/man" pid=2710 comm="man" capability=1  capname="dac_override"`
About my `dmesg`, it is quite long, also it like the same syslog (just different timestamp. Should I upload it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One concern is that modern Windows 10 systems almost never actually *shutdown* and instead hibernate. You would be surprised the amount of additional work needed to fully shutdown a modern Windows system. Without fully shutting down the hard drive is often left in a state that may not be accessible. Although, typically when this happens the disk will not mount at all and you wouldn't be able to see the directory contents.

The other concern is that when using USB thumb/pen drives they typically have very poor reliability. They are designed to be written to infrequently and running a full operating system on them usually degrades their write cycles to the point where writes fail. (See [Thumb Drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_flash_drive) and [Memory Wear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_memory#Memory_wear))

Comment: So that means I could not turn a pendrive into portable OS? If so, do you have any suggestion for making a portable OS where I could carrying around?

Comment: No, it mean you CAN but with caveats: Read the links. Reality isn't black&white.

Comment: Yeah, I read the link. But I just couldn't image the lifespan of pendrive if I install an OS on it? (16GB space)